# Ergodic type ODE problem

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, elliptic-pde, differential-operators

Define the second order linear differential operator associated with $X$ (Here $X$ is the unique strong solution to appropriate Ito SDE) by $$A = \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2(x) \frac{d^2}{dx^2} + \mu(x) \frac{d}{dx}. $$ 
Now the ODEs of type $(A-r)f(x) + g(x) = 0$ can be solved easily using the resolvent operator defined by
$$
(R_rf)(x) = \mathbb{E}_x \left[ \int_0^{\infty} e^{-rt}f(X_t)dt \right]
$$
 (i.e minus the inverse operator of $A-r$) yielding the following
$$
f(x) = (R_rg)(x) + dk_r(x),
$$
where $k_r(x)$ is a solution to pde $(A-r)f(x)=0$. The solutions $k_r(x)$ are well behaved and kind of easy to handle so they cause no problems. But now I’m dealing with ode which is a of type
$$
Af(x)+g(x) = \beta,
$$
where $\beta$ is a constant. The same reasoning here however doesn’t work as applying the resolvent $R_0$ leaves me with
$$
f(x) = (R_0)(g+\beta)(x)+dk_0(x)
$$
And this can’t be right as for the resolvent $R_0$ the integral 
$$
(R_0\beta)(x) = \mathbb{E}_x \left[ \int_0^{\infty} \beta dt\right]
$$
diverges.

Are there any known methods that give solution to the ODEs of the second type that works in this kind of framework? (So I’m not looking for uniqueness or existence results, just solution methods)

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind is re-writing the equation as $\tfrac{d}{dm(x)}\tfrac{d}{ds(x)} f(x) = \beta - g(x)$, where $m$ is the speed measure and $s$ is the scale function, and then undoing the derivatives. I do not know a good reference; a quick google query gives several reasonable documents, like [this one](https://www.math.wustl.edu/~sawyer/hmhandouts/OneDimDiffuseOps.pdf).

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki That might work for my purposes. I’ll try to work it out. I haven’t seen the representation of the operator $A$ in terms of speed measure and scale function before, strange that the standard textbooks don’t cover it.

Comment: This representation does not seem to be well-known outside probability crowd. I searched a bit, and I found that Richard Bass wrote about it in chapter IV of his book [*Diffusions and elliptic operators*](https://books.google.pl/books?id=tbzgBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover). Judging by the author only, this must be a good read.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki  I’ll certainly have a look at that book. Btw after undoing the derivatives it looks kind of nasty. Does any nice intuitive interpretation come to your mind, I mean do you recognize any ’well-known’ things in it?

Comment: I suppose it is the double integral in $f(x) = f(0) + \tfrac{df}{ds(x)}(0) s(x) + \int_0^x \int_0^y (\beta - g(z)) dm(z) ds(y)$ that looks nasty to you? I am afraid that I do not have much intuition behind this: the double integral is related to the Green function for $-A$ in $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$; I'll think about the details and extend this comment later today.

Comment: The Green operator for $-A$ on $(0, \infty)$ that I mentioned above is the inverse operator $G=(-A)^{-1}$ on $(0, \infty)$, defined by a similar double integral: $Gf(x) = \int_0^x \int_y^\infty f(z) dm(z) ds(y)$. If $f$ is integrable, then $s(x) \int_0^\infty f(z) dm(z) - G f(x) = \int_0^x \int_0^y f(z) dm(z) ds(y)$ is the integral we are interested in. The Green operator has a nice probabilistic interpretation: $Gf(x)=\mathbb{E}_x\int_0^\tau f(X_t)dt$, where $\tau$ is the hitting time of $0$. But I do not know equally nice interpretation of the other term $s(x)\int_0^\infty f(z)dm(z)$.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Yes it was the double integral. But your explanation is certainly good enough. I’ll let you know if I come with something for the second term later on.